# Using Modernizr to style input:focus, input:active

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

How can I test for and style input:focus and input:active in IE7/8 (which don't support these properties) using Modernizr?

Or should I just use basic JS/CSS to do so? What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution outside of Modernizr, but it works very much the same way (by adding an element to the DOM, styling it's `:hover` state, and then testing if the state has happened).

Kudos to James Padolsey for [this article](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fixing-focus-in-internet-explorer/).

You may have to check for other events than `mousedown` and `mouseup` for the active state, but this seems to work for modern browsers (maintaining native `:focus` and `:active` states) as well as IE7 (with the fake `.focus` and `.active` classes).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/c4XET/11/)

Comment: That would override the default styling in chrome

Comment: I added an idea to my original post to remove the default-override I had going on earlier.

Comment: your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/c4XET/2/) adds focus styling to chrome when it already has a native focus styling. I'm looking for a way to detect if the browser has a native focus styling (or failing that, a list of which browsers do/don't provide native focus styling) so I can include/exclude them in my css rules

Comment: Ok, I see what the issue was.  Maybe try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/c4XET/8/)?  Does this do what you were looking for?  The function is from [this article](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fixing-focus-in-internet-explorer/).

Comment: Just realised I've been asking for the something I don't need. IE9 does provide a default style for :focus, it's just very hard to spot and I need to overrule it. I would have had the problem with IE7 not supporting :focus though, so that jQuery plugin is useful. I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: Well, I'm glad this was useful to you.  For anyone else who's looking for this too, I'll post my updated fiddle in my actual answer.  Thanks for the bounty!  Good luck with your project.